# Do I need a transit Visa, if my layover at LHR airport is of 20 hours extending on to the next day

Tags: indian-citizens, canada, layovers, transit-visas, lhr

I am an Indian Citizen traveling to Montreal, Canada via LHR airport on a study permit. My layover at LHR(London-Heathrow) is 20 hours which goes to the next day. Consequently, I'll have to recollect my entire checked in baggage and get it rechecked for the next flight which binds me to go through the immigration again.

I wish to ask if I would need a transit visa or any other such document?

Answer (score 1):

You will not need a visa, as long as UK Border Force can verify your Canadian visa (not a problem as long as you have a sticker in your passport - some countries such as Australia do not issue these). See [this gov.uk page](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no).

If you do not have a visa sticker in your passport for whatever reason, you will need to check with your airline that they are able to verify your Canadian visa so that they will flag on your Advance Passenger Information for the UK.

Comment: Thanks @jacoman891. I found the answer [here](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/yes)